# Open datasets on homeschool students vs traditional students

Tags: data-request, research

I'm doing a project for my stats class. I need to do 5 hypothesis tests with the same dataset: testing means, testing medians, testing standard deviations (or variances), testing proportions, testing for associations with categorical data, and linear regression.

If you have any other suggestions as to a different/easier dataset to use that'd be great too.